# Visual Studio light bulb no longer shows "Fix format"

Tags: visual-studio, format

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019

Using C#, this is about what appears in the light bulb tips...
I used to be offered a Quick Action (QA) to fix the format, but that QA no long appears.
For example, a QA used to appear when I had no spacing around binary operators, like this:

```
    if    (File.Exists(subsFile)&&(subsFile.Length>5))
```

It would correct to:

```
if (File.Exists(subsFile) && (subsFile.Length > 5))
```

The problem started when I clicked on a QA that I was curious about (but I cannot remember what it was).  I assumed there would be a simple way to undo whatever effect it had, but I was wrong.

If I do Ctrl-K Ctrl-D, then the line would be corrected as above.

I have checked the options in the Tools>Options... menu, and the spacing seems to be correct.
I have looked carefully through the Code Styles options, but nothing seems to apply.

I have searched the web at length, including Microsoft and, of course, stackoverflow, and found nothing to help.

It is annoying that I cannot use a feature supplied by Microsoft to help novices like me.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Not a serious problem, but it annoyed me so much that I ran Visual Studio Installer and chose the Repair option. (It's on the Start menu in Windows 10.) This didn't solve the problem on its own, and may not have been necessary for the solution.

Next I had a look at the file .editorconfig (found in Solution Explorer).  Previously when I considered this, it seemed to entail a huge learning overhead, and it scared me off, but this time I spotted this line in the file:

dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-Style.severity = none

When I changed this to:

dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-Style.severity = severity

and saved the file, the problem went away like magic.

I don't know enough to explain why this worked.